# Too big for him

Tags: vocabulario, gramática

While translating the phrase, “too big for him,” should we use "por" or "para"? In other words, which one of the below would be correct Spanish:

1. > *Esa broca es demasiada pequeña **por** esta pared.*
2. > *Esa broca es demasiada pequeña **para** esta pared.*

Comment: As I edited @fedorqui answer, it should be **demasiado**, not demasiada. This is because here it works as an adverb not an adjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use:

> Es demasiado grande para él

Because the following does not have any meaning:

> Es demasiado grande por él

So in your case, use the seconde phrase:

> Esa broca es **demasiado** pequeña para esta pared

Comment: I’ve noticed that demasiada is still given as the feminine form of demasiado by the dictionaries. Could you please provide me any scenario in which this feminine form should be used? In this example I was expecting demasiada to go with broca which doesn’t seem to be the case now.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia As I said in the previous comment, it depends on the role of `demasiado` in the sentence. In this case is an **adverb** (a `Complemento Circunstancial de Cantidad`), and adverbs _do not_ need an agreement of gender and number with the noun, because they don't modify the noun. E.g.: `Esas brocas son **demasiado** grandes para esa pared`. In the other hand, `demasiada`, `demasiados` and `demasiadas` are **adjectives**, which have to be in the same gender and number as the noun, they modify the noun. E.g.: `Esa mujer tiene **demasiadas** brocas`.